# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar por pantalla el coste del vuelo si es igual al del prompt?

Tags: javascript

Quiero poder introducir en el *prompt* un precio que si coincide con el coste de algún vuelo se imprima por pantalla y si no coincide salga un *alert* y se repita el ciclo hasta introducir un número que coincida.

```js
let flights = [
    { id: 00, to: 'Bilbao', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 1600, scale: false },
    { id: 01, to: 'New York', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 700, scale: false },
    { id: 02, to: 'Los Angeles', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1100, scale: true },
    { id: 03, to: 'Paris', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 210, scale: false },
    { id: 04, to: 'Roma', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: false },
    { id: 05, to: 'London', from: 'Madrid', cost: 200, scale: false },
    { id: 06, to: 'Madrid', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 90, scale: false },
    { id: 07, to: 'Tokyo', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1500, scale: true },
    { id: 08, to: 'Shangai', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 800, scale: true },
    { id: 09, to: 'Sydney', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: true },
    { id: 10, to: 'Tel-Aviv', from: 'Madrid', cost: 150, scale: false }
];


    function exPrice(){
      document.write('<h1>Vuelos con el mismo precio </h1>');
      let equalNum;
      for (let i = 0; i < flights.length; i++){
        do{
          equalNum = parseInt(prompt('Introduzca el precio exacto:'));
          if(equalNum === flights[i].cost){
            document.write('Vuelo con origen: ' + '<strong>' + flights[i].to + 
            '</strong>' + '  Destino: ' + '<strong>' + flights[i].from + '</strong>'  +' 
             coste: '+ '<strong>'+flights[i].cost+'</strong>'+'€' + '<br/>');

          } else{
            window.alert("El precio no coincide con ningun vuelo, introduce otro 
           precio");
          }
        }while(equalNum !== true);
      }
    }
    exPrice();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según puedo ver tu código me parece que está al revés el *do while* debería estar afuera y el *for* dentro, para que de esta forma cuando introduzcas un valor compare uno a uno los objetos del *array* que tienes y si ninguno coincide se active el *do while* y repita la operación, modifiqué un poco tu código para que veas de que hablo (Lo dejaré comentado):

```js
let flights = [
    { id: 00, to: 'Bilbao', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 1600, scale: false },
    { id: 01, to: 'New York', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 700, scale: false },
    { id: 02, to: 'Los Angeles', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1100, scale: true },
    { id: 03, to: 'Paris', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 210, scale: false },
    { id: 04, to: 'Roma', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: false },
    { id: 05, to: 'London', from: 'Madrid', cost: 200, scale: false },
    { id: 06, to: 'Madrid', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 90, scale: false },
    { id: 07, to: 'Tokyo', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1500, scale: true },
    { id: 08, to: 'Shangai', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 800, scale: true },
    { id: 09, to: 'Sydney', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: true },
    { id: 10, to: 'Tel-Aviv', from: 'Madrid', cost: 150, scale: false }
];

function exPrice() {
    document.write('<h1>Vuelos con el mismo precio </h1>');
    let equalNum = false; // Creamos la variable para controlar si se encontró el costo igual
    do {
        const num = parseInt(prompt('Introduzca el precio exacto:'));
        for (let i = 0; i < flights.length; i++){
            if (num == flights[i].cost) { // Comparamos el costo del objeto con el valor ingresado
                // Si entra es igual mostramos por pantalla, equal cambia a true y finalmente rompemos la iteración para que no siga comparando los demás valores (break)
                document.write('Vuelo con origen: ' + '<strong>' + flights[i].to + '</strong>' + '  Destino: ' + '<strong>' + flights[i].from + '</strong>'  +' coste: '+ '<strong>' + flights[i].cost+'</strong>'+'€' + '<br/>');
                equalNum = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!equalNum) // Si el for terminó de recorrer y no encontró ningún valor igual al costo mostramos la alerta
            window.alert("El precio no coincide con ningun vuelo, introduce otro precio");
    } while (!equalNum); // La condición es que si equalNum es false siga iterando hasta que sea true
}
exPrice();
```

Hay formas más sencillas de hacer este proceso pero en este caso me limitaré a utilizar el código que tenias, si tienes alguna duda escríbela en los comentarios. ;)

Comment: funciona perfecto, ya me parecía a mi que el for no estaba donde tenia que estar, muchas gracias